# Does objective c need a standard to define a memory model like c++ 11?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, clang

As we knows that CPU and compiler may reorder our code, when we load/store a shared memory, the result is undefined if we don't involve lock (or some similar tools). C++ 11 comes up with [memory model](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model) to define the behavior when multi-thread operate a shared memory.

Will OC code be reordered by clang or CPU ? if so, if OC should have a standard like memory model in C++ 11 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory model link you provided basically is saying:

1. Race conditions exists between threads
2. Cache coherency issues, such that one thread writes to A then B, but another thread sees the change on B before the change on A, is a real thing.
3. Lockless programming between threads is extremely hard to get right, but here's the rope (std::memory_order) if you like to do things the hard way.
4. Using lock primitives (including std::mutex) is the solution to writing correct multi-threaded code.

Even if Objective-C hasn't formally documented a memory model per se, the same data races and coherency issues exist. And using correct thread/locking primitives is still the solution.